# Access enum name through reflection

Tags: java, reflection, enums

I am trying to access the name of an enum through reflection (the `name` field of the `Enum` class) but I get a `NoSuchFieldException`.

See below a simple example: the program prints `5` for the Integer but throws an Exception for the enum.

Is there an elegant way to get the `inspect` method to work for enums?

```
public class Test {
  static enum A {
    A;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Integer i = 5;
    System.out.println(inspect(i, "value")); // prints 5, good

    A a = A.A;
    System.out.println(inspect(a, "name"));  // Exception :-(
  }

  private static Object inspect(Object o, String fieldName) throws Exception {
    Field f = o.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    f.setAccessible(true);
    return f.get(o);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getField` or `getDeclaredField` methods will only return positive results for fields declared in called class. They will not search for fields declared in superclasses. So, to get the refference for name field, you'll need to go deeper. Get the superclass reference (which in your case will be `Enum` class) and search for name field there.

```
o.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
```

Comment: Of course - thanks. I was focused on the enum part and missed the super class part.